# Are these metrics?

Tags: general-topology, inequality, algebraic-topology, metric-spaces

I want to find if the below functions are metrics. I have worked through each of the three conditions, but am stuck on the positivity of $f(a, b)$ (first condition-see below) and the triangle inequality of $g(a, b)$ (third condition-see below).

> **Edit:** Have now solves these two parts, see the answers for positivity of $f(a, b)$  and the triangle inequality of $g(a, b)$

Please could you help me on these two points?

> $f(a, b)=a^2+ab+b^2$

1. Initially I thought this would not satisfy positivity. But for $f$
   to be negative, $ab$ must be negative, and greater in modulus value
   to $a^2+b^2$. So for this to work, $a$ and $b$ must be opposite sign
   and less than $1$. I have tried small opposite signed values of $a$
   and $b$ but have not found $f(a, b)$ to be positivity. **Not sure.**
2. Symmetry. $f(b, a)=b^2+ba+a^2=a^2+ab+b^2$ so this is satisfied
3. Triangle inequality. Is $f(a, b)+f(b, c) \geq f(a, c)$ satisfied? Let $X=f(a, b)+f(b, c)-f(a, c)=a^2+b^2+ab+c^2+b^2+cb-a^2-c^2-ac=b^2+ab+cb-ac$. Assume $X \geq 0 $ for all $a, b, c \in \mathbb{R}\implies b^2 +ab+cb \geq ac$. My initial thought is that if we take $b$ to be very small and $a$ and $c$ to be comparatively larger, then we may arrive at a contradiction. Take $b=0.01, a=100, c=100 \implies 0.0001+2 \geq 10000$. Contradiction. Triangle inequality does not hold.

> $g(a, b)= \frac{|a^3-b^3|}{2}$

1. Positivity satisfied since $|x| \geq 0 \forall x \in \mathbb{R}$ and $2 \geq 0$
2. $g(b, a)=\frac{|b^3-a^3|}{2}=\frac{|-(-b^3+a^3)|}{2}=\frac{|-1||a^3-b^3|}{2}=\frac{|a^3-b^3|}{2}=g(a, b)$. So symmetry is satisfied.
3. Must consider the sign of: $X=g(a, b)+g(b, c)-g(a, c)=\frac{|a^3-b^3|}{2}+\frac{|b^3-c^3|}{2}-\frac{|a^3-c^3|}{2}$ For the triangle inequality to be satisfied $X$ must be positive. I tried to find some counter-examples, such as take $a=100, c=0 \implies \frac{|100^3-b^3|}{2}+\frac{|b^3|}{2}-\frac{|100^3|}{2}$. But if $b$ is positive then the whole thing is positive. If it is negative , then the first two terms are positive and larger than the third. From this reasoning, I believe $X$ is *always* positive and the triangle inequality holds.  **Not sure.**

Comment: If (as you say) you have found values of $a$ and $b$ that give $f(a,b) < 0$, then you're done. This already shows that $f$ can not be a metric.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So $$|x|+|y|\ge |x+y|,$$ then

$$\frac{|a^3-b^3|}{2}+\frac{|b^3-c^3|}{2}=\frac{|a^3-b^3|+|b^3-c^3|}{2}\ge$$
$$\ge \frac{|a^3-b^3+b^3-c^3|}{2}=\frac{|a^3-c^3|}{2}$$

Comment: ah yes. I think I should have the inequality in the back of4 my mind when doing such questions.

Comment: So $X=g(a, b)+g(b, c)-g(a, c)=\frac{|a^3-b^3|}{2}+\frac{|b^3-c^3|}{2}-\frac{|a^3-c^3|}{2} \geq \frac{|a^3-c^3|}{2} - \frac{|a^3-c^3|}{2} =0$. Hence the triangle inequality is satisfied

Comment: amiz9: Yes, exactly

Answer (score 1):

$f(a,b)=a^2+ab+b^2 \geq \frac {1}{4} a^2 + ab + b^2=(\frac {1}{2} a + b)^2 \geq 0$.

This shows that your $f$ satisfies non-negativity condition.

Comment: perfect thank you. I would never have thought of using that method. I guess it makes sense since completing the square gives a positive term

Comment: @amiz9 Surely makes sense.

Answer (score 1):

$f(a,a)=3a^2\ne 0$ so $f$ cannot define a metric.

Comment: which property does this fail?

Comment: @amiz9 The property that distance from point $a$ to point $a$ should be equal to zero for every point $a$.

Comment: oh yes thanks. So this should be one of the first things I should check since it does not take long to calculate